# How to find out how much of a time period is inside working time and how much is outside of this time?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

To calculate working hours, I need to separately calculate the number of hours that the user worked during working hours(**09:00 - 17:00**) and outside of working hours (overtime) and return their sum.

For example, the user worked from **2023-01-23 15:00** to **2023-01-23 22:00**, which is **2023-01-23 15:00** to **2023-01-23 17:00** in the working hours and **2023-01-23 17:00** to
**2023-01-23 22:00** is overtime.

Now, how can I find out how much of the user's working hours are within the range of **9:00** to **17:00** and how much is outside the hours?

```php
foreach ($timeSheets as $key => $time) {
    if ($time->is_in == 1) {
        $time_in = new Carbon($time->event_at);
        $time_out = new Carbon($timeSheets[$key + 1]->event_at);
        [$time_in, $time_out] = $this->getTimeZoneName($bill->BillingRateTimezone->timezone, $time_in, $time_out);
        // period of his/her work time
        $start_time = $time_in->format("H:i");
        $end_time = $time_out->format("H:i");

        // How can I calculate how much of user work time is between 9:00-17:00 and how much is outside of this  ??
                        
        $sumOfInside = "?";
        $sumOfOutside = "?";
    }
}
```

Comment: Find any ranges where both the start and end DateTimes lie between 9:00 and 17:00, and separately find any outliers (where both are between 12:00 to 8:59 and 17:01 to 11:59). Have you tried anything? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75987690/edit) and include any code you've tried, and any errors.

Comment: @TimLewis  ok, check it again

Comment: Cool, so you have `Carbon` instances of `$time_in` and `$time_out`, you can check if _both_ of those are between `9:00` and `17:00`, but you'll need to define `$workDayStart` and `$workDayEnd` _somehow_, then do `if($time_in->between($workDayStart, $workDayEnd) && $time_out->between($workDayStart, $workDayEnd) { $sumOfInside += $time_in->diffInHours($time_out)); }` (or similar). Check the Carbon docs for available functions and see what you can come up with: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/. You'll also have to handle partials, i.e. `$time_in` is `9:00`, but `$time_out` is `17:10`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a better way to go around it but a bunch of conditionals to cover every case could work.

Case 1:

```
         [-------------]                                         user hours  
                         [------------------]                    9:00 to 17:00  
  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  
  0    2    4    6    8    10   12   14   16   18   20   22   24
```

Case 2:

```bash
                                              [-----------]      user hours  
                         [------------------]                    9:00 to 17:00  
  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  
  0    2    4    6    8    10   12   14   16   18   20   22   24
```

Case 3:

```
                           [-------------]                       user hours  
                         [------------------]                    9:00 to 17:00  
  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  
  0    2    4    6    8    10   12   14   16   18   20   22   24
```

Case 4:

```
                   [-------------]                               user hours  
                         [------------------]                    9:00 to 17:00  
  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  
  0    2    4    6    8    10   12   14   16   18   20   22   24
```

Case 5:

```bash
                                 [-------------]                 user hours  
                         [------------------]                    9:00 to 17:00  
  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  
  0    2    4    6    8    10   12   14   16   18   20   22   24
```

Case 6:

```bash
                    [--------------------------]                 user hours  
                         [------------------]                    9:00 to 17:00  
  |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |  
  0    2    4    6    8    10   12   14   16   18   20   22   24
```

Using `Carbon` 's diff method can be very helpful for this, but since datetimes are needed, `Carbon::today()` (or simply `today()` if you want to use the laravel helper) can give us a date with it's time at 00:00:00, which is perfect for our needs. As for getting the sum, we can incrementally add to a couple of instances of `CarbonInterval`.

```php
$inside_working_time = CarbonInterval::make('0h 0m 0s');
$outside_working_time = CarbonInterval::make('0h 0m 0s');

// start and end of work day
$_9 = Carbon::today()->add('9h');
$_17 = Carbon::today()->add('17h');
foreach (...) {
    ...
    $user_start = Carbon::today()->add($time_in->format('H\h i\m'));
    $user_end = Carbon::today()->add($time_out->format('H\h i\m'));

    $inside_working_interval = CarbonInterval::make('0h 0m 0s');
    $outside_working_interval = CarbonInterval::make('0h 0m 0s');

    // Case 1
    if ($user_start->lessThan($_9) && $user_end->lessThanOrEqualTo($_9)) {
        $outside_working_interval->add($user_start->diff($user_end));
    }
    // Case 2
    elseif ($user_start->greaterThanOrEqualTo($_17) && $user_end->greaterThan($_17)) {
        $outside_working_interval->add($user_start->diff($user_end));
    }
    // Case 3
    elseif ($user_start->greaterThanOrEqualTo($_9) && $user_end->lessThanOrEqualTo($_17)) {
        $inside_working_interval->add($user_start->diff($user_end));
    }
    // Case 4
    elseif ($user_start->lessThan($_9) && $user_end->between($_9, $_17)) {
        $inside_working_interval->add($_9->diff($user_end));
        $outside_working_interval->add($user_start->diff($_9));
    }
    // Case 5
    elseif ($user_start->between($_9, $_17) && $user_end->greaterThan($_17)) {
        $inside_working_interval->add($user_start->diff($_17));
        $outside_working_interval->add($_17->diff($user_end));
    }
    // Case 6
    elseif ($user_start->lessThan($_9) && $user_end->greaterThan($_17)) {
        $inside_working_interval->add($_9->diff($_17));
        $outside_working_interval->add($user_start->diff($_9);
        $outside_working_interval->add($_17->diff($user_end));
    }

    $inside_working_time->add($inside_working_interval);
    $outside_working_time->add($outside_working_interval);
}
```

And then you can either print out the interval with the `forHumans()` method or get the total hours and minutes.

```
$inside_working_time->forHumans() // (string) 'X hours and Y minutes'

$inside_working_time->cascade()->h // (int) hours
$inside_working_time->cascade()->i // (int) the minutes that remain

$inside_working_time->totalHours // (float) hours expressed as decimal (for example 7.333 hours for 7h 20m
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-time

For instance with the method [diffInBusinessMinutes](https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-time#diffinbusinessminutes) you get a number of minutes in, and with Carbon diffInMinutes, you get the total, so minutes out are the first subtracted from the total.